# Is a list or tuple a function? (trying to use tuple as a key in a sorted() function.)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I a beginner learning python and doing some [python exercises](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/basic) and I have a generic question about why one piece of code works and another does not. 
This code I wrote below works just fine:

```
def sort_last(tuples):
  def MyFn(tuples):
    return tuples[-1]
  a = sorted(tuples, key=MyFn)
  return a
```

Intuitively I thought this might work and tried it. It does not:

```
def sort_last(tuples):
  a = sorted(tuples, key=tuples[-1])
  return a
```

Will someone explain why the second piece does not work?
I have looked it up: [#sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)
Is it because a list or tuple is not a function? Is it because it is more than one argument?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's worth noting that the `MyFn` function that you define in the first version of the code gets called with a *single* value from your sequence, so your argument name should probably be different. It's not illegal to reuse the name, but it does make it a bit harder to understand.

Answer (score 4):

From the Docs:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element

So, you could pass a callable object with one argument. You could rewrite second example with lambda:

```
def sort_last(tuples):
    return sorted(tuples, key=lambda t: t[-1])
```

Or, as suggested by @ersran9, you could use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
import operator

def sort_last(tuples):
    return sorted(tuples, key=operator.itemgetter(-1))
```

Comment: I guess using `operator.itemgetter` would be neater.

Comment: And the reason your code didn't work was that `key=` would be evaluated there and then, getting as its value a static reference to the last element from `tuples`.

Comment: @tripleee, Not sure if I understood you correctly - which code didn't work?

Comment: Sorry, that was directed at the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the reason why your second code snippet doesn't work is that the "key" parameter to the sorted function is supposed to contain a recipe for an item's sorting weight.  The sorted() function will run this recipe on every item in the list you're sorting.  When you say key=tuples[-1], the expression "tuples[-1]" is evaluated once, right away.  The result of that evaluation is the last tuple in the list, which is passed into the sorted function.  The sorted function is expecting a recipe (a function) that can be executed; it gets a tuple instead, and tuples can't be executed.  (What would executing a tuple even mean, anyway?)

When you say "tuples[-1]", you're running a computation to extract the last element from a variable.  When you say "MyFn", you're referring to the recipe without running it.  If you want a syntax that looks like "tuples[-1]", you can use the lambda operator as noted in soon's answer.

To see this in action, we can follow my personal programming motto:  "When in doubt, print stuff out."  If you don't fully understand what your program's doing, you can insert print statements all over the place to give you a better idea of what's happening.

Here's a version of your program with some informative print statement:

```
def MyFn(tuples):
    print "inside MyFn: tuples =", tuples, "returning", tuples[-1]
    return tuples[-1]

tuples = [("a", 3), ("b", 2), ("c", 1)]
print "sorting: tuples =", tuples

a = sorted(tuples, key=MyFn)
print "the sorted list is", a
```

and the output is very informative:

```
sorting: tuples = [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
inside MyFn: tuples = ('a', 3) returning 3
inside MyFn: tuples = ('b', 2) returning 2
inside MyFn: tuples = ('c', 1) returning 1
the sorted list is [('c', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

As you can see, the "sorted" library function calls your MyFn recipe three times!

This output also makes it obvious that there's a little style issue with your code.  You're using the variable name "tuples" for different things at different places in your program.  In MyFn the name refers to a single tuple, whereas at the outer level it refers to the initial unsorted list of tuples.  Your code works, but it is confusing!  I suggest using a different variable as the argument to MyFn, like this:

```
def MyFn(e):
    return e[-1]

tuples = [("a", 3), ("b", 2), ("c", 1)]
a = sorted(tuples, key=MyFn)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is False Code Dont Put function in an Other function;
Using OOP Programming Or Takeout the function (MyFn)>
like this :

```
def sort_last(tuples):
   a = sorted(tuples, key=MyFn)
   return a
def MyFn(tuples):
   return tuples[-1]
tubles=("var","share","far","Bar")
print MyFn(tubles)
print sort_last(tubles)
```

Or by The OOP Programming :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Mr_sam:
        def sort_last(self,tuples):
                self.tubles=tubles
                a = sorted(tuples, key=self.MyFn)
                return a
        def MyFn(self,tuples):
                self.tubles=tubles
                return tuples[-1]
tubles=("var","share","far","Bar")
Go=Mr_sam() #Take a Object from class Mr_sam Go is a copy from Mr_sam
print Go.sort_last(tubles);Go.MyFn(tubles) # take the 2 attribute from Object Go
```